How to translate a textview behind a window with animation
I can animate a TextView across the screen but how would I animate it so that it appears only after a margin from the left and disappears at a margin on the right?  Is this possible without doing some crazy masking geometry?
The code below just takes it from off the screen to off the screen.
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textview);

final float toXDelta = 1000;
final float fromXDelta = -1000;
final int animationDuration = 3000; // Animation duration in ms

tv.setText("101010010101000110101010101");
TranslateAnimation animator = new TranslateAnimation(fromXDelta, toXDelta, 0, 0);
animator.setDuration(animationDuration);
animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
tv.setAnimation(animator);
animator.start();

I want the animation to appear and disappear from and into some margins.

There are a couple of things that pop to mind.


I'm assuming you've tried getting the dimensions of the screen and setting fromX and toX to those values w/ an offset?


You could bount the animation to a view which itself has some margins on it, so it doesn't reach the screen border


You could apply a simultaneous Alpha animation on it and tweak it so the text "disappears" as you approach the edges


Let me know if you need clarity on any of those approaches and I'll formulate them into answers.

Just to be clear, I want a ticker tape effect where the text scrolls past and disappears.  So only a window of the entire text is visible at any given time.  I can do it, but it takes the entire screen width.  I want the text to appear as though it is scrolling only within the bounds of a TextView who's dimensions I set.  I'm looking for the easiest solution.

I was able to scroll text with an invisible TextView stacked ontop of an opaque view but I wasn't able to restrict the scrolling text within the opaque TextView.

Bounding the animation to a view sounds like the ideal way to do it.  I'm guessing that means the animation is contained in the view and not the activity view. I would love an example.  I'll try it in the meantime.

Do I just have to wrap my animated TextView in a view other than the root view and the animation will be contained within that?  I hope that is it, but I'm going to feel dumb.

That was it.  I feel so dumb.  I should have posted my XML so it would have been easier for people to see how dumb I was.  You can post the answer if you'd like as I'm guessing that was your #1 suggestion.

@slowcoder would you mind sharing your working solution? I'm in a similar situation where I want my view to slide to the left of the screen up to a certain margin, but I'm not quite sure how to do it without specifying the actual amount of pixels for it to move. The pixel solution seems flakey because my app is going to be running on multiple screen sizes.

Nevermind, got it. For anyone wondering, here's what I did: binding.container.animate().x(binding.root.x + rootViewPadding).setDuration(500).start(). For some reason I didn't realise I could just animate towards a specific X coordinate :)

Glad you figured it out!
Sorry I missed the comment notifications!

You need to bound your animation to the parent/root view bounds, and then  set fromX and toX to those values w/ an offset.
